Performance Problem CFAR Algorithm (Python) - DSP for Radar
I programmed different types of 1D OS (ordered statistic) CFAR (constant false alarm rate) algorithms to detect potential targets in rows/columns of Range-Doppler Maps which are calculated from real radar data. The code in itself works fine and I am able to find the desired targets with it. The only problem is that my function is really slow (half a second or more per frame, the elapsed time depends a little bit on the size of the Range-Doppler Map). Below is the code I wrote:
@jit(nopython=True)
def cfar_1d(spectrum : npt.NDArray, direction : str, cfar_mode : str, guard_cells : int, ref_cells : int, beta_dB : float) -> npt.NDArray:

    # calculate index for kth value 
    kth = int(np.ceil(ref_cells * 3/4))

    # generate a vector containing all detections
    threshold = np.zeros((1, len(spectrum)))
    lead_array = np.zeros(ref_cells)
    lag_array = np.zeros(ref_cells)
    spectrum_length = len(spectrum)

    # compute the threshold for each bin
    for i in range(spectrum_length):
        lead_idx = 0
        lag_idx = 0
        
        for j  in range(i - (guard_cells + ref_cells), i - (guard_cells)):
            current_idx = int(get_idx(j, spectrum_length, direction))
            lag_array[lag_idx] = spectrum[current_idx]
            lag_idx = lag_idx + 1 

        for k in range(i + (guard_cells), i + (guard_cells + ref_cells)):
            current_idx = int(get_idx(k, spectrum_length, direction))
            lead_array[lead_idx] = spectrum[current_idx]
            lead_idx = lead_idx + 1

        # compute the threshold according to CFAR mode
        if(cfar_mode == 'GOS'):
            cfar_val = np.sort(np.concatenate((lag_array, lead_array)))[kth]
            threshold[:,i] = 10**(beta_dB / 10) * cfar_val
        else:
            # sort the arrays
            lag_sorted = np.sort(lag_array)
            lead_sorted = np.sort(lead_array)
            # try different "kind" of sorts: quicksort, heapsort, mergesort, timsort
            
            # get the reference values
            lag_val = lag_sorted[kth]
            lead_val = lead_sorted[kth]
            
            if(cfar_mode == 'GOSCA'):
                threshold[:, i] = 10**(beta_dB / 10) * (lag_val + lead_val)/2
            elif(cfar_mode == 'GOSGO'):
                threshold[:, i] = 10**(beta_dB / 10) * max([lag_val, lead_val])
            elif(cfar_mode == 'GOSSO'):
                threshold[:, i] = 10**(beta_dB / 10) * min([lag_val, lead_val])
              
    return threshold

I also programmed a helper function to get the right index depending on whether range or doppler data is feed into the algorithm. This distinction is necessary as the 1D CFAR function is used in another function, to calculate the 2D CFAR over all range and doppler bins of a Range-Doppler Map.
@jit(nopython=True)
def get_idx(count : int, length : int, mode : str):

    if(mode == 'range'):
        if (count < 0):
            return np.abs(count)
        elif(count >= length):
            return (2 * length) - count -2
        else:
            return count
    elif(mode == 'doppler'):
        if(count < 0):
            return count + length
        elif(count >= length):
            return count - length
        else:
            return count


One of the first things I tried and am still using right now is the numba package to use the JIT Compiler. This helped a little bit but not as much as I had hoped. I also tried modifying the code as shown in the snipped down below. This did produce similar results as I would get with my original code but not exactly the same and performance wise there was hardly any difference.
        if i < guard_cells + ref_cells:
            for j  in range(i - (guard_cells + ref_cells), i - (guard_cells)):
                current_idx = int(get_idx(j, spectrum_length, direction))
                lag_array[lag_idx] = spectrum[current_idx]
                lag_idx = lag_idx + 1 
        elif i > spectrum_length - guard_cells - ref_cells:
            for k in range(i + (guard_cells), i + (guard_cells + ref_cells)):
                current_idx = int(get_idx(k, spectrum_length, direction))
                lead_array[lead_idx] = spectrum[current_idx]
                lead_idx = lead_idx + 1
        else:
            lag_array = spectrum[i-guard_cells-ref_cells:i-guard_cells]
            lead_array = spectrum[i+guard_cells:i+guard_cells+ref_cells]

For me the most difficult thing is, to enhance the performance of the code while still preserving the overall functionality. Maybe one or some of you could help me with that. I am happy to answer any questions that might occur.
[EDIT] Following given advice I will give a minimal reproducible example here to better show my problem.
The 1D CFAR function is used in another function of mine which calculates a 2D CFAR over the whole input map.
def cfar_2d(rd_map : npt.NDArray, settings : dict, curr_idx : int) -> npt.NDArray:
    if(len(rd_map.shape) > 2):
        threshold_map_r = np.zeros((rd_map.shape[1], rd_map.shape[2]))
        threshold_map_d = np.zeros((rd_map.shape[1], rd_map.shape[2]))
    else:
        threshold_map_r = np.zeros((rd_map.shape[0], rd_map.shape[1]))
        threshold_map_d = np.zeros((rd_map.shape[0], rd_map.shape[1]))

    # CFAR in range direction
    for i in range(rd_map.shape[0]):
        threshold_map_r[i, :] = sp.cfar_1d(rd_map[i,:],
                         direction = 'range',
                         cfar_mode = settings['cfar_r_mode'],
                         guard_cells = settings['cfar_r_guard_cells'],
                         ref_cells = settings['cfar_r_ref_cells'],
                         beta_dB = settings['cfar_r_beta_dB'])
    for i in range(rd_map.shape[1]):
        threshold_map_d[:, i] = sp.cfar_1d(rd_map[:,i],
                         direction = 'doppler',
                         cfar_mode = settings['cfar_d_mode'],
                         guard_cells = settings['cfar_d_guard_cells'],
                         ref_cells = settings['cfar_d_ref_cells'],
                         beta_dB = settings['cfar_d_beta_dB'])

    # single detection maps
    detection_map_r = rd_map >= threshold_map_r
    detection_map_d = rd_map >= threshold_map_d
    # combined detection map
    detection_map = np.logical_and(detection_map_r, detection_map_d)
    
    return detection_map, detection_map_r, detection_map_d

And now a small example program. White Gaussian noise is used as the test input.
import numpy as np
import time as time
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def main():
    grid_size = (100, 100)
    noise = noise.normal(0, np.sqrt(0.25), grid_size)
    peak_position = (grid_size[0]//2, grid_size[1]//2)
    peak_amplitude = 10
    noise[peak_position] += peak_amplitude
    noise = np.abs(noise)**2

    settings = {
        'cfar_r_mode'        : 'GOSCA',
        'cfar_r_guard_cells' : 1,
        'cfar_r_ref_cells'   : 16,
        'cfar_r_beta_dB'     : 16,

        'cfar_d_mode'        : 'GOSCA',
        'cfar_d_guard_cells' : 1,
        'cfar_d_ref_cells'   : 16,
        'cfar_d_beta_dB'     : 16
    }
    start_time = time.time()
    detections,_,_ = cfar_2d(noise, settings)
    stop_time = time.time()
    elapsed_time = stop_time - start_time
    print(f'Elapsed time: {elapsed_time} seconds.')

    plt.figure(figsize = (12,8))
    plt.clf()
    plt.imshow(detections, origin = 'lower', 
               aspect = 'auto', cmap = 'viridis')
    plt.title('Detections')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()

I also tried using a "profiler" (snakeviz) to "profile" my code. Unfortunately, as I have never used a "profiler" before I could only find out that the 1d_cfar function is the one that makes the whole program very slow but I could not exactly find out which part of the function seems to be the problem. (Maybe someone could give me advice?)

"my function is really small" did you mean slow? it's not "small" -- this is a programming problem, unlikely to be generally useful to other people. you should "profile" your code using a "profiler"

To get the kth smallest value from an array, you can use np.partition (like this). Also, this technique may be useful.

instead of np.abs(count) you can return -count since count is negative in this branch

better use integer flags instead of strings. Define somewhere RANGE_MODE = 0, DOPPLER_MODE = 1, etc. and use instead

If you want some better help its best here to provide minimal, reproducible example. Help people helping you help you better :)

consider that you presented 119 lines of code. don't make us work on your specific application. simplify this, remove the specifics, keep the core idea. you can then transfer that onto your problem, once someone has solved the core problem.

If there is a "profiler" that can "profile" jit functions, I'd like to know about it too... A practical (even for beginners) profiling approach is to replace some part of the code with a dummy and compare the performance. For example, get_idx can be replaced with j % length. Of course, this will produce wrong results, but it will show you how much the get_idx function is slowing down your code. And you've already got some good advice in the comments above on how to improve it.

Also, you should never use a small example when measuring performance, as this will hide the real bottleneck. In fact, your example is so small that using np.partition instead of np.sort, as I commented above, would have the opposite effect. However, if the array is large enough, this should be an effective change. So you have to try it with an realistic size example.
